# Why "created_at" wrong time when saved to database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I check time on Rails in my production server

```
$ rails console production
$ Time.now # good time
```

On Mysql production

```
mysql > select now(); # good time
```

but after I'm saving any record to database, "created_at" and "updated_at" fields are -2 hours from current time. What is wrong here?

I have restarted mysql, nginx after time changes. What can I do next? Is it Rails of Mysql define time for these fields?

Comment: you checked rails timezone?

Comment: Lithuania has UTC+02:00 - exact the (unsigned) time difference you detected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because the timezone your data is saved in the db is `UTC`. If you want to change it to local, set in `application.rb`:

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

and you should declare explicitly your timezone if you haven't yet:

```
config.time_zone = 'Vilnius'
```

Comment: You saved my life brother. Thank you for research of my living location and fixing the issue I was facing for over 3 hours :)